# How to get all Zendesk help articles using their API

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

We have a search function on our website. I need to index all of our Help Desk articles from Zendesk so that they will appear in search results. I currently have the following code, but it will only return the first 30 results.

```
const https = require('https');
const { Textify } = require('../common/Textify');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function GetZDeskArticles() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const request = https.request(
      'https://example.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/en-us/articles.json',
      (response) => {
        let data = '';
        response.on('data', (chunck) => {
          data = data + chunck.toString();
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
          const body = JSON.parse(data);
          res(body.articles);
        });
      }
    );   

    request.on('error', (error) => {
      rej(error);
    });

    request.end();
  });
}

async function StoreZDeskArticles() {
  const zdeskArticles = await GetZDeskArticles();
  let arts = [];
  zdeskArticles.forEach((art) => {
    if (art.draft) return;
    art.body = Textify(art.body);
    arts.push(art);
  });

  let storagePath = path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    '../',
    '_data',
    'ZenDeskArticles.json'
  );
  fs.writeFileSync(storagePath, JSON.stringify(arts), 'utf8');
}

StoreZDeskArticles();
```

If I add `?page%5Bsize%5D=100` to the request url, I obviously will get the first 100 results. But I have 164 articles in total that I need to index. I have read through the [Zendesk pagination documentation](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/introduction/pagination/) and am unsure of how apply their solution to my situation.

Comment: Would a search be conceivably be done that would return all 164 results? I wonder if that would not be a very useful search.

Comment: I need to index all search articles so that when a search is performed, the system can return any and all articles that match the search terms. If only some of the articles are indexed, then the search results could possibly be missing very relevant information.

Comment: Righto, I see - that makes sense. Would you add the pagination link you are looking at, into your question?

Comment: OK, so what problem did you encounter? There seems to be two pagination mechanisms - cursors and [offsets](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/introduction/pagination/#using-offset-pagination). Offsets is probably easiest, and seems to make use of the `page` query string parameter - you'll need to do multiple calls. You could do 6 lots of 30, into which your 164 rows would fit.

Answer (score 1):

For pagination: In the returned JSON, there is a section "links" where there is an entry "next", that is the URL to the next page of articles that you need to perform your next request to.

For offset: In the returned JSON is an entry "next_page" that gives you the next page. However, it is recommended to use pagination instead of offset, as it has better performance.

For both solutions: You iterate over requests, using the "next" or "next_page" entry for follow-up requests until the respective entry is null, then you have seen all articles.

https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/introduction/pagination/